# Why is responseText returning blank?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, responsetext

I have a database table whose fields contain latitude and longitude coordinates of positions.  I want to create markers for a Google Map view using the information from the database.

I've implmented the query function as

```
function getCords(){
  $link = connectDB();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tour";
  $results = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  $jsonArray = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $jsonArray[] = array('fileName' => $row['FileName'], 'lat' => $row['Lat'], 'lon' => $row['Lon']);

  }

return json_encode($jsonArray);
}
```

When I call this function from a php page, it returns the usual JSON format.

My issue is executing an ajax query.  I have the query function above in a php scripts file containing six or so utility functions controlling login, logout, registration and the like.  To query the database via jquery, I tried

```
var request = $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=cords",
  type: "json"
});

var response = request.responseText;
```

My problem is the response is always empty.  Is this due to the formation of the URL or for some other reason?

Comment: Because the response is not returned from the server when that line of code is exexcuted.

Comment: @Vega, the fact that the server is not returning a response is self-explanatory, but my question was why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=cords",
      dataType: 'json', // necessary, because you're sending json from server
      success: function(response) {  // response will catch within success function
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
```

or

```
   var request = $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=cords",
      dataType: 'json', // necessary, because you're sending json from server
    }).done(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
```

#### NOTE

Instead of `return json_encode($jsonArray);`, use `echo  json_encode($jsonArray);`

Comment: you can also do `request.done(function(response){ console.log(response);});`

Comment: @KevinB I was going to write that an another answer :P.. Something like `request.done(console.log(request.responseText));`

Comment: @KevinB I added that, it looks right? if not you can edit. I want to learn

Comment: @thecodeparadox, I made the changes, and the responseText still returns null.  Stepping throuogh the query function shows that the jsonArray is being populated with correct values, they're not appearing in Firebug.

Comment: @Jason instead of `return json_encode($jsonArray);`, use `echo  json_encode($jsonArray);`

Answer (score 0):

The response is blank because the response is not returned from the server when that line of code was executed. Try to set the responseText inside ajax callback. See below,

```
var response = '';
var request = $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=cords",
  type: "json"
}).done (function (data) {
   console.log(data); //json object as jquery converts it for you
   console.log(request.responseText); //string text as returned the server.
   response = request.responseText; 
   //^-- response is a string text as returned the server.
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hUY6v/

Answer (score -1):

see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), You are not using correct format, thats why response is blank.

Success handler will return the response from server end. So use it like :

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=cords",
      type: "json"
      success : function(response){
               console.log(response);
        }
   });
```